# AIX and rpm problem

Tags: rpm, aix

Today on Aix 7.1 with yum

```
yum -y update

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================
 Package                            Arch                     Version                           Repository                        Size
======================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 openldap                           ppc                      2.4.56-2                          AIX_Toolbox                      4.3 M
 p11-kit                            ppc                      0.23.16-2                         AIX_Toolbox                      4.3 M
 p11-kit-tools                      ppc                      0.23.16-2                         AIX_Toolbox                      199 k
 python                             ppc                      2.7.18-2                          AIX_Toolbox                       22 M

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       4 Packages

Total size: 30 M
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2) is needed by python-2.7.18-2.ppc
libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2) is needed by python-2.7.18-2.ppc
libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2) is needed by openldap-2.4.56-2.ppc
libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2) is needed by openldap-2.4.56-2.ppc
Please report this error in http://yum.baseurl.org/report
** Found 25 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
curl-7.74.0-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
curl-7.74.0-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-3.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
flrtvc-0.8.1-1.ppc has missing requires of /bin/ksh93
git-2.20.4-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
git-2.20.4-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
httpd-2.4.46-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
httpd-2.4.46-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
krb5-libs-1.18.3-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
krb5-libs-1.18.3-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
libssh2-1.9.0-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
mod_ssl-2.4.46-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
mod_ssl-2.4.46-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
openldap-2.4.56-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
openldap-2.4.56-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
python-2.7.18-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
python-2.7.18-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
python-pycurl-7.43.0-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so)
python3-3.7.9-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
python3-3.7.9-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
rsync-3.2.3-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
stunnel-5.56-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
stunnel-5.56-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
wget-1.20.3-1.ppc has missing requires of libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.2)
wget-1.20.3-1.ppc has missing requires of libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.2)
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with: yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2021-05-25-13-054OMsxg.yumtx
```

I copy the archive on my homedir and extract it

```
cp /usr/lib/libssl.a .
ar x libssl.a

ls libssl.so*
libssl.so*  libssl.so.0.9.8*  libssl.so.1.0.0*  libssl.so.1.0.2*
```

The library exist why rpm cannot find it?

The strange thing is the package works, on another aix(7.2) I have an identical problem, yum cannot update the system, but if I use

```
yumdownloader --resolve mypackage
rpm -Uvh --nodeps --force *rpm
```

the packages install and run fine.
I have tried to rebuild the db of rpm but nothing change

Comment: Is `openssl.base` installed? Also, you might demonstrate the full paths in the `ls libssl.so*` command -- I assume it's /usr/lib?

Comment: of course in installed `lslpp -L |grep -i ssl
  openssl.base            1.0.2.2101    C     F    Open Secure Socket Layer`

Comment: Maybe the `rpm`-based updates have left the lpp database out of sync or vice-versa. Does running `updtvpkg` help any?

Comment: I will try with updtvpkg

Comment: Thanks, the updtvpkg works fine. If you add as answer I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the RPM database has become out of sync with the current system; run [`updtvpkg`](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/understanding-aix-virtual-rpm-package-rpmrte) to improve the situation.